# Writing Eigen vector to a library in a tab delimited fashion

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I'm currently writing a bunch of values to an eigen array during a for loop. I want to write the state of that Eigen array to that file after every iteration of the for loop in a tab delimited fashion. However, in the way I'm currently doing it, I'm writing the file and it just appends the values of the eigen array onto the column that the previous vector is already on. The result is files that are 1 columns thats 200,000 entries long where they should be 200 columns that's 1000 entries long. Quick example code below to show the process.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<Eigen>

using Eigen::VectorXd;

int main()
{
    std::ofstream myfile1;
    VectorXd en(1000);
    std::string energyname = "Energies.txt";
    myfile1.open(energyname);
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
        {
            en(j) = 10;
        }
        myfile1 << en << std::endl;
    }

}
```

How do I reword this so that it doens't append the code onto the back of the end of the output

Comment: I edited the post. This is on a windows machine

Comment: I'm using visual studio. All the compilation is happening in there. I use Notepad typically but the result is the same in notepad++

Comment: Have you verified that your example here duplicates the error? Are you modifying the locale of `myfile1` at all anywhere in your actual program? I'm not on my Windows machine so I can't verify this myself.

Comment: No it is all done inside the for loop  and no change in the file name.

Comment: The code you are showing would (after fixing some typos) actually output each vector vertically, i.e., essentially 200000 values separated by `'\n'` (and some filling spaces). Please make sure that you post the exact code which reproduces your behavior (i.e., a [mre])! The code you posted does not even compile (due to some trivial typos).

Comment: Oh my goodness. I can't believe I didn't look hard enough at `VectorXd`. OP is making a vector of 1000 rows. You should be printing out one long column like @chtz said. Are you getting a column? And calling it a row? Is every element on its own line?

Comment: Also check the timestamp on the file. There's the possibility that you're looking at an old file, or that you have the file open in one place so that your program isn't able to open it.

Comment: I apologize @chtz . I've since fixed the code and adjusted the equation so that it says "columns". The code above I can confirm compiles in my Visual Studio Distrobution.

Comment: To be clear, you don't want 200 columns of 1000 elements each, right? You still want 200 rows of 1000 elements each?

Comment: Either one will work. The plotting I'm going to do with them will all be done in matlab so primarily, I just need to tackle the issue of writing all of the data into one large monolithic column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VectorXd` is a column vector. If you actually want a row vector, you need `RowVectorXd`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <Eigen>

using Eigen::RowVectorXd;

int main()
{
    std::ofstream myfile1;
    RowVectorXd en(1000);
    std::string energyname = "Energies.txt";
    myfile1.open(energyname);
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
        {
            en(j) = 10;
        }
        myfile1 << en << std::endl;
    }

}
```

If you actually need a column vector, and just want to print the transpose of this column vector, you can use [`Eigen::IOFormat`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/structEigen_1_1IOFormat.html) to change the end-of-row separator from `"\n"` to `" "`. This is the 4th parameter to `IOFormat` so we need to re-pass defaults to the first 3 parameters.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<Eigen>

using Eigen::VectorXd;
using Eigen::IOFormat;
using Eigen::StreamPrecision;

int main()
{
    std::ofstream myfile1;
    VectorXd en(1000);
    std::string energyname = "Energies.txt";
    myfile1.open(energyname);

    IOFormat column_transpose_format(StreamPrecision, 0, " ", " ");

    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
        {
            en(j) = 10;
        }
        myfile1 << en.format(column_transpose_format) << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Neither of these are tested.

Comment: Edited my previous comment

Comment: Disregard previous comment. I put it in as you requested and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

`std::endl` puts the character represented as `\n`

In Linux this is enough to mark the end of a line.

But in Windows two characters are used: `\r\n` (a.k.a. 'LF-CR')

If you read your file with a simple reader (Notepad) it will not separate lines if the end-of-line mark is just `\n`

Using LFCR mark, your code may look like this:

```
myfile1 << en << "\r\n";
```

Comment: This is being compiled, run, and executed on windows. The locale should be set for Windows and `std::endl` should widen to `"\r\n"`. OP also states that the issue persists on Notepad++.

Comment: `std::endl` is essentially equivalent to `'\n'` followed by `std::flush`. Whether `0x0a` or `0x0d 0x0a` is put into the file depends on the locale as well as whether the file was opened in binary mode.

Comment: This change did not fix my issue. I still have the error where the code all returns an outfile of 200,000 entries in a row